# What should the "elevator pitch" for our site be?

Tags: discussion

This is from the [7 essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) and is related to Rob Stevenson-Leggett's question [What should the FAQ Contain?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-the-faq-contain).

In looking at the FAQ's for other Stack Exchange sites ([bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq)) the convention seems to be that SE sites include their "elevator pitch/tagline" at the very top of the FAQ. So the question is what is our elevator pitch?

From 7 essential meta questions about a site's "elevator pitch":

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger.
> You have precisely one floor to describe this community to them. What
> would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes
> what this site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> - the tagline
> - the motto
> - the blurb under the logo
> - a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
>
> For more detail see: [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to get my head wrapped around this how about an elevator pitch of:

> *The Tridion Stack* is your source of expert answers for project managers, developers, testers, architects, administrators, and
>   businesses using or thinking about using the Tridion Web Content
>   Management System

And a Tag Line of `Expert Answers for Tridion Professionals`

Comment: This is about right. Not sure about "The Tridion Stack". Maybe we could miss out project managers :-)

Comment: 'Tridion - Stack Exchange' just doesn't sound right to me. Maybe 'The Tridion Stack Exchange site?' I'm ok removing project managers as the general 'and businesses' is a broad enough catch all to include them.

Comment: @DominicCronin I saw a question the other day which reffered to the site a 'The Tridion Exchange' maybe that is the way to go for the site name. Not as geeky as something like 'The Tridion Stack' and it works better when used in a sentence then 'Tridion - Stack Exchange' does.

Answer (score 2):

From Broker to Events, from Component to Published Page we can help with all your Tridion questions. No Schema too big, no Blueprint too small. Just ask and the best Tridion minds in the business will do their best to help.

(Mostly tongue in cheek. Some of this stolen from Dave Houlker)

Comment: Directly from Mike Percival's business cards!

Answer (score 1):

Once people needed permission and private accounts to ask Tridion questions online in a place called `The TridionWorld Forum`. Over a decade, users forgot their accounts and the rest of the internet seemed to get much faster than TridionWorld.

But now `Tridion StackExchange` lets anyone interested in Tridion, the ability to quickly ask and answer questions and get explicitly rewarded for their efforts with points and badges. Such online points and badges make asking and answering Tridion questions even *more* addicting.

And now you can easily find Tridion answers along with feedback on how good these answers are with just an internet search.