# Using SE as an alternative to ideas.sdltridion.com

Tags: discussion

This is just an idea (no pun intended) but couldn't we make the whole ideas.sdltridion.com site obsolete by simply adding an ideas tag to our StackExchange site?
We can identify the submitter, we have a voting system in place, and it is super convenient. We just have to promote a discussion into an idea!

And best of all: people actually follow this site..

Your votes please :-)

Comment: You'd need Product Management to read this site :)

Comment: Another point for using SE instead imo :)

Comment: @Nuno are you not planning on being a regular here?

Comment: So how would we do this? With just an "ideas" tag?

Comment: On Meta questions, if I'm not sure on the suggestion, but think it's a good question, do I vote up or down? For example, I think we *should ask if SE is an alternative to the Ideas site*. +1, right? Even though I'm not sure yet if it really *should* be an alternative.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Exchange works really well for technical support issues, but it should not be used to replace customer support services such as vetting feature requests. There's a good meta post covering the issue below and the top two answers are worth reading:

[Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project)

Your idea is not without merit — folks try to retrofit Stack Exchange to submit ideas where folks can vote on a variety of other *stuff.* But Stack Exchange isn't a simple voting engine, and that's not really what we do.

Thank you for your suggestion, but I'm afraid it's just not a good fit for *this* site.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think this would be a good fit for the sit as it doesn't seem like it is the type of Q&A the SE sites are really designed for.

Such questions really do not seem to meet the spirit of being `practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face` and in our discussion of [What should the FAQ contain?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-the-faq-contain) one of the items Henderik proposed in an upvoted comment which I added into my suggested FAQ text is:

> Issues like bug reporting, feature requests, generalized discussions, specific customer support issues do not fit into this site's Q&A model, and will be quickly closed by the community.

Beyond that, even though we could add an `ideas` tag the 'voting' mechanism in the Main Tridion SE site is not really suitable for voting on something like a feature request given the effects it has on a user's reputation (positive and negative.) I guess you could tag the questions as community wiki questions to prevent that.

The Meta Tridion SE site does not have the same effect on reputation. However, based on the activity we've had on Meta vs. Main so far I would say most normal users wouldn't visit meta as a regular activity (if ever.)

I'll admit it has been a while since I checked out the Ideas site and the last time I was there it seemed pretty dated with a large number of items at the top of the list being ones which were already part of the product.

With that said, I think a better idea would be for us to push SDL to replace the current Ideas site with a more open (not requiring an SDL provided login/password) site driven by something like User Voice and then periodically promote that site through the Community Bulletin feature of our SE site.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I'll put my Product Manager hat and reply on this one.

1. This may be a good place to discuss whether something *should* be in the product, but it doesn't make it official
2. Perhaps, as a customer, I wouldn't really want my idea to be placed on a public site that anyone can read.
3. We do read ideas. Just 2 months ago I went through ~340 ideas and scoped them in (or out) for future releases. Due to some of the challenges we're having with that site's back-end, the site does not reflect this effort yet (you guessed it, that site does NOT run on Tridion)
4. Most of the audience here is fairly technical, so I would expect that 75% of ideas suggested would be around "adding support for Database X", or "make it work with $RandomMvcPlatform". While those ideas are great, believe me, our product architecture team is well aware of the platforms we must support, whether they're suited for enterprise customers (I talk to our customers quite often) *and* I read what people ask for in forums such as this one.

We are having some challenges with the Ideas site, not going to deny that. It was an "inherited" platform from another SDL division and it isn't optimal, but it is what we have. If you feel that you have a brilliant idea for the product, and you absolutely must let us know about it, and cannot get into the [Ideas](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/) website, then, by all means, [contact me](http://www.linkedin.com/in/nunol).

With that said, Stack Exchange (via the [Tridion tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tridion), and now this site) has been quite a boost to the Tridion Technical community, and I believe it has provided a lot of help to new implementers. Learning a new platform on anything is not easy, particularly when it is a platform that is as extensible (read: [complex](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/complex-is-not-difficult-just-like-simple-is-not-always-easy)) as Tridion is. This is what Stack Exchange was meant to do, and I think most of us have been having quite some fun while helping each other.

I have also advised many customers to ask their implementation questions on Stack Overflow, it doesn't make it a replacement to Customer Support, but a complement. Crowdsourcing if you will.

I'm fine with you guys tagging something as an idea, or "enhancement request". But don't expect Tridion to implement it because it got 300 upvotes on StackExchange. I may look into it, and even ask for more detail on how exactly something like you propose could work on the product and still be supported on the various platforms we support and not break anything in the near future, but the main source for our backlog (from the outside of SDL) remains the Ideas website.

Answer (score 4):

I think this site should stick with the Questions and Answers format, and we should not try to push it into something which attracts endless discussion. While you could see an enhancement or feature request as a question which could be answered, I think before it gets a final answer/decision, it should have some discussion around it, and that last part is not something I would see fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I started question in a new "Ideas" section in the Developer group for SDL Web on SDL Community.

No feedback yet, but we'll see if you're interested in interacting with SDL Web and Product Management through that feature.

See some [example non-product questions for now in the Ideas section](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/i).