# Crowd-Sourcing for the product roadmap

Tags: discussion

This question is basically the opposite of [this one](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/using-se-as-an-alternative-to-ideas-sdltridion-com) where Quirijn asks if we could use StackExchange as a way to provide Enhancement Requests for SDL Tridion.

If you read through the answers in that question you'll notice that

1. that's not what StackExchange is for and
2. we already have a mechanism for you to let us know what you'd like in the product.

So... my question is the opposite. If I'm planning to build something new in the product (for sake of argument, let's take the example of supporting cloud/noSQL databases) would this site be a good platform to ask the technical community for feedback?

Could I create a question here that would ask, for instance, which NoSQL database(s) should we add support for? Or is this stretching the limits of the StackExchange mandate?

Comment: Not answering your question, but NoSQL db to add support for == ravenDB :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm generally all for it, but we are stretching the limits a bit indeed. Typically if your question is about SDL Tridion and generally covers...

- Programming related to Tridion and Tridion extensions
- Integrating Tridion with other projects
- Designing, deploying, administering or operating Tridion-based systems

It is considered on topic (which already is debatable with your question).

Then taking into account we should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Since chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Then I have to conclude that you should not ask it on the main site itself.

Knowing that discussions are a perfect fit on meta, so you might consider using meta for your question. On the other hand, if nobody opposes you asking this question on the main site directly, I will gladly follow (as I see the importance of asking these type of questions and value the feedback/opinion of our community).

Comment: Maybe indeed I could just ask them on Meta. Interesting point, thanks for the feedback Bart.

Comment: I wonder what would happen to SDL Tridion Ideas though. Would all discussion and activity happen here? And would accepted ideas still be shown there? The Ideas "accepted" badges might be as coveted as SE badges. :-)

Comment: By "here" I meant Meta. +1 to TRex Meta as a good place for SDL Tridion-related product discussions. Honest community feedback preferred (even if "negative") over (just) rants, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: [SDL Web/Tridion Ideas](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl_web_ideas) has been official for awhile now. The other SDL Products have also created Idea sites.

We're trying out an "Ideas" feature on SDL Community to solicit ideas from the community.

See some [example non-product questions in the SDL Web Developer group](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/i).

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Bart as we may be stretching limit asking off-topic or open ended question - Consider we have close so many such question.

I would say, we should make use of the CHAT functionality of the TRex.

May be we can raise a question in Meta for a scheduled CHAT session with the Agenda consisting of question you are willing to ask