# Where do you store your Tridion-related Designs and Documentation?

Tags: discussion

Nearly all* of the Tridion implementations I've helped with had documentation. This included:

- Functional Designs
- Technical Designs
- Architecture Designs
- Infrastructure Documentation
- Other Project-specific information such as End-User Training

*I wish it was really all.

Especially for end-user help, I've seen everything from example sites, to an internal blog, to Wikis or SharePoint.

**Where or how do you typically store these artifacts?**

**If you had to create a "Wiki Module" for DXA, for example, what technologies would you use?**

This line of question is partly curiosity but *could* be related to [Crowd-Sourcing for the product roadmap](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/269/46).

Edit: I'm mentioning [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) (flat website generator) and [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com) in case anyone has worked with something similar.

Answer (score 2):

We use Google Sites at the moment, but considering changes

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Is this for your team or client's use? And if for clients, do you make these visible from the CME (Custom Page, Slide Out Nav, etc.)?

Comment: We use it for both. Internally for details like servers, environments, VPNs etc... and externally for content how to's and project documentation. It works great internally, as we use Google Apps for our email and calendars. Externally it is not as great, due to the need for google email address. We will sometimes add it as a dashboard link in the CME, depending on the customer preference really. It is great to also select someone on the customer side to "own" it, so it continues to evolve after the project ends.

Answer (score 1):

Alvin, this is just a suggestion, You can upload your documents on SDL Media Manager as a file and access it from your custom page within the CMS.

Comment: That'd be nice for videos, but who's making videos for their editors aside from [certain universities](http://www.medicine.yale.edu/web/support/intro/guide/basics.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Wer're using Confluence for one client for most of our designs and docs. This has let us use a lot of it with custom urls for their editors.