# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion

Based on the fact that the StackExchange moderators [rejected Glenn's request](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-the-faq-contain#comment144_3) to update the FAQ and deferred it to our community moderators I thought I'd kick things off in nominations for those moderators!

Based on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/ it looks like the nominations could be influenced by a question like this with nominations.

So who should be the Tridion Stack Exchange Pro Tem moderators?

Either nominate someone or yourself! Post a short recommendation for why please and try and follow the format others have used below e.g

Nominee: [Nuno Linhares](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/33/nuno-linhares) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33/nuno-linhares))

[image: profile for Nuno Linhares on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Nuno is one of the key individuals behind the Community and MVP program. His reputation speaks for itself, and not only the amount of answers he has given, but certainly also his comments and revisions show he cares enough to make this site a success and is willing to dedicate the time to make it work.

Comment: From everything I've read on meta stack overflow it seems sites get a minimum of three moderators. To ensure this community retains a balanced, independant voice it seems like we would be better off having 2 of the 3 moderators from outside of SDL.

Comment: I think most of the SDL contributors here care enough about the community to understand that sometimes you need to wear a different hat - but fair enough, that's the same principle behind the MVP Selection Panel (at least 60% are externals)

Comment: I deleted my multiple nomination answer so only a single answer per nominee remains for better visibility. I nominated Chris Summers (Chris dedicates a lot of his time to our community), Alvin Reyes (He is our most prolific commenter, always having something interesting to add to any answer or discussion), Glenn Stevens (Very active here on meta, obviously seeing the importance of it) and Rob Stevenson-Leggett (In my vision one of our rising stars, somewone with a lot of drive). And I gladly accept my nomination of course.

Comment: Thanks Bart (and thanks for the nomination) - it seems to work better with one per post.

Comment: @NunoLinhares hope you didn't read my comment as me impinging upon the reputation of any individual contributor from SDL.

Comment: No worries @GlennStevens :)

Answer (score 12):

Nominee: [Nuno Linhares](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/33/nuno-linhares) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33/nuno-linhares))

[image: profile for Nuno Linhares on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Nuno is one of the key individuals behind the Community and MVP program. His reputation speaks for itself, and not only the amount of answers he has given, but certainly also his comments and revisions show he cares enough to make this site a success and is willing to dedicate the time to make it work.

Answer (score 10):

Nominee: [Glenn Stevens](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/39/glenn-stevens) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39/glenn-stevens))

[image: profile for Glenn Stevens on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Glenn Stevens has been active in reviews, asking questions, editing, voting, participating here in meta, has contributed to the tag wiki and helped the site get to the beta phase by referring 13 committers to the site's area 51 proposal.

Answer (score 9):

Nominee: [Bart Koopman](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/89/bart-koopman) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/89/bart-koopman))

[image: profile for Bart Koopman on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Bart represents SDL's Community Development outreach, has been doing a fair number of reviews and edits, has answered a number of questions and has participated here on Meta and has done a bang up job on a number of the tag wiki pages.

Bart referred 52 committers to the proposal for this site and in a good position to promote the site to the wider Tridion Community.

Answer (score 9):

Nominee: [Chris Summers](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/53/chris-summers) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/53/chris-summers))

[image: profile for Chris Summers on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Chris was a strong supporter of the Area 51 proposal referring 27 committers. During the beta phase he has been very active in asking and answering questions, voting, editing and participating in this meta site.

Answer (score 9):

Nominee: [Alvin Reyes](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/46/alvin-reyes) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46/alvin-reyes))

[image: profile for Alvin Reyes on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Alvin is always around to share his views an opinions. He would make a good Pro Tem moderator as he has been active in asking questions, voting, editing and participating here on meta. Add to that the views he shares on his [blog](http://www.createandbreak.net/), he is in a good position to promote and guide our community.

Comment: Woot, thanks for the blog plug, Bart. Speaking of which, TRex is definitely a [win for technical communities](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/03/seven-wins-in-developing-technical.html).

Answer (score 7):

Nominee: [Rob Stevenson-Leggett](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/43/rob-stevenson-leggett) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43/rob-stevenson-leggett))

[image: profile for Rob Stevenson-Leggett on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Rob Stevenson-Leggett would make a good non/SDL Pro Tem moderator as he has been active in asking questions, voting, editing and participating here on meta. Rob is also in a good position to promote the site to the wider Tridion Community through the blog posts he writes for Building Blocks.

Comment: A big +1 for Rob - a SE vet and Tridion MVP who has done as much as anyone to get this site off the ground.

Comment: I concur. One of the problems with creating the answers for Him, Chris and Bart is it means I couldn't actually up vote them but all three should have +1 next to their name's from my perspective.

Answer (score 7):

Nominee: [Frank van Puffelen](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/28/frank-van-puffelen) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28/frank-van-puffelen))

[image: profile for Frank van Puffelen on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Frank is the all time top user for the [tridion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tridion/topusers) tag on Stack Overflow. His reputation there speaks for itself, unfortunately he hasn't been that active on here yet.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for considering me. Although I have indeed been less active in the Tridion community in the past few months, I will gladly help moderate T-rex and keep it as clean as the community wants it.

Answer (score 6):

Nominee: [Quirijn Slings](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/85/quirijn) ([Meta Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/85/quirijn))

[image: profile for Quirijn on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Quirijn has helped maintain the tags on the main site and contributed to meta. As an MVP he is very active in the Tridion community and leads the DD4T project. This includes regular help for people on the DD4T mailing list.

Answer (score 5):

Nominee: [Dave Houlker](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/35/dave-houlker) ([Meta-Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35/dave-houlker))

[image: profile for Dave Houlker on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Dave got us all started with his proposal for a [tridion](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion) site on Stack Exchange, seeing the need for a separate site. He visits this site several times each day (check his profile on when he was last seen).

Answer (score 4):

Nominee: [Ant Plant](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/78/ant-p) ([Meta Profile](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/ant-p))

[image: profile for Ant P on Tridion Stack Exchange]

Ant has been vocal on meta and answered questions on the main site. He has a good understanding of how Stack Exchange works and is enthusiastic about Tridion.