# Does anyone have any suggestions for edits to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

Based on the responses to [What should the FAQ Contain?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-the-faq-contain) I have updated the [the FAQ](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/faq?) with Glenn's excellent answer.

Can anyone interested have a quick read and let me know if there are any suggestions below please?

Comment: Just to be clear, my answer is only excellent because it captures the collective thinking of Nuno, Ant P, Hendrik, Ashok, Alvin and Rob.

Comment: Why does this question have the word "Final" in it. Surely the FAQ is something to be modified over time and based on experience. Perhaps even.... <dramatic pause> based on the questions that are frequently asked!

Comment: Fair point. I meant final before the first time we had the opportunity to update it. Edited.

Comment: I've updated the FAQ to reflect the suggestions from Shog. He was right in that the text he wrote for the about page covers everything we were trying to convey in our longer previous bulleted lists. The FAQ might continue to need some tweaks but it looks much better now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reviewing the final results, I gotta tell you: it is *long*!

I'm no Tridion expert, but I have to assume that *most* of what you're itemizing in the "what can I ask here" list are things that most people would *expect* a site dedicated to Tridion to allow. As such, you can probably get away with using *much* broader categories, and then calling out the exceptions. For example:

> If your question is about SDL Tridion and generally covers...
>
> - Programming using Tridion and Tridion extensions
> - Integrating Tridion with other projects
> - Designing, deploying or operating Tridion-based systems
>
> And is not about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to Tridion
> - Tridion pricing, careers, job postings, or referrals for implementation consultants

I've gone ahead and used these simplified on/off topic lists on [the Tridion about page](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/about) (which you can also edit) - I strongly encourage you to follow this model on the /faq as well - remember, it's no good if people don't read and remember it, and folks tend to do better with short (3-5 items max) lists.

Comment: That is definitely a more concise list that seems to cover what we were trying to convey. If we used that list along with what we have in the block quote about implementation specific questions, not putting customer specific information in your questions etc. it would make that section of the FAQ much stronger.

Comment: yeah totally agree, I think this covers my question about it too. And we always have the option to mention that certain questions are not a match for this site afterwards. Its not like we get thousands of questions a day here (maybe some day ;o)

Comment: Should it be 'Programming using Tridion and Tridion extensions' or 'Programming related to Tridion and Tridion extensions'? I actually edited the about page to reflect 'related to Tridion...' as it seemed more accurate.

Comment: I'll defer to your expertise on the matter then, @Glenn

Answer (score 2):

Looks great although I'm wondering if we should elaborate a bit more on the following:

- Implementation-specific topics like

  - How do I insert a carousel on this page?
  - How do I update my navigation/sitemap?
  - Where should I create content for the French site?

Agreed we don't want to see question like: "How do I insert a carousel on this page", but a implementation questions related to this would be valid I think. Thinking something like: "I'm trying to insert a carousel on my page but I can not render the value of my embedded field?".

For number two: "I publish my sitemap from Tridion, using a TBB in a PT, but my loop over the root SG organizational items contains Pages and SGs, how do I filter this to only SGs?"

And for the last one: "Do you separate Country content and Language content in different Publications and how doe that fit in a diamond model BluePrint?"

Comment: Bart, the thinking behind that section of the FAQ was to discourage questions about how to perform editorial tasks related to the way a specific customer has implemented Tridion. After reading your response and re-reading the FAQ I realize I did a poor job of wording that specific item in the FAQ but I am not sure exactly how to word it to make it clearer. I think your suggestion for the first bullet works well but I am not sure your suggestions for the second two bullets will work.

Comment: Maybe change "Implementation-specific topics" to "The content entry fields unique to an editor's organization" or similar (authors may not recognize the fields they see as part of an "implementation" but just part of Tridion as they know it). I'd like to leave TRex open to questions from content editors, but keep it clear this isn't end-user support. We're probably ok removing the point for now--when have you seen a *question* from a non-implementor?

Comment: Yeah Alvin, that is also exactly what I meant indeed.

Comment: Very clearly - if you have had a weird or bizarre implementation done, and don't understand it, we can't help you, but many of the patterns and practices around the use of Tridion are /highly/ relevant here and it would be against all we set out to do here if such questions were excluded.